# cross correlation of two string in c++

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, matrix, cross-correlation

Consider I have two matrices of 1's and 0's. I want to save it as `bool Matrix` but `opencv` doesn't store that way instead it is stored as `uchar Mat`. Therefore my space increase by 8 times. (each element is 8 bit instead of 1 bit).

My code is basically as follows:

```
Mat mat1, mat2; //I want each index to be 1 bit 
load(mat1);     //data size is not important in memory
load(mat2);
corr2(mat1, mat2); //this corr2 is same as Matlab's cross correlation.
```

I'm doing this part 10M times. Therefore loading takes so much time. My matrices are 1K*1K, so I m able to store them as 1 MB but I want them to be 128 KB (matlab stores as 178 KB approx).

Here is my question: I want to store my matrices as `string` and instead of `Mat` operation, I want to use string.

For example, size of `mat1 and mat2` is **2*8**.

**mat1:**

```
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 (66=B)
0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 (122=y)
```

**mat2:**

```
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 (67=C)
0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 (122=z)
```

I will store `str1=By` and `str2=Cz`

**Is there a way to cross correlate str1, str2?**

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This is not an answer, but rather a long comment. I'm posting it as an answer in order to avoid spamming the comments section of the OP.

Storing 1M elements of numeric type is never going to be a problem on any modern computer.

You should learn a little bit more about C and memory storage; bool is not an elemental type, and bool storage therefore only exists virtually. Packing several bits into a char is a good idea, but you should have a look at C++'s [bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/) if you want to be efficient.

Understand that there might be a significant difference between the way you store your data on hard-disk, and the format that is best suited for processing of active memory (eg RAM). This is probably the reason behind the odd size for Matlab's storage; storing additional information and/or in seemingly inefficient storage units is often desirable to make the algorithms easier to write and the elementary operations execute faster on CPU.

Overall, I think the advantage of switching to "bool-packed chars" storage like you suggest would be negligible in terms of processing speed, and will certainly incur a difficult programming work and obscure the process of maintenance. You are better off sticking with chars for the processing and switch to single-bit storage for write-on-disk operations.

Comment: if you are doing this operation 10 millions of time, that is a really big problem. Each load operation takes 20-30 ms `10^7*25ms = 250000 sec = 4200 min = 70 hrs = 3 days.` If I can decrease from 25 ms to 3 ms, loading time will be `9 hrs`

Comment: What prevents you from loading the matrices in batch? A cache system loading 1GB of memory at at time is totally acceptable; that would be 1M of your matrices. Duplicate that for the storage of results and it is still fine. 10 large read/write on disk operations for a processing of that size is acceptable too :)

Comment: 1GB memory can only load 1024(1K) files not 1M files. Even if I can load 1M files at a time, still I'm loading 1TB. Why should I load 1TB instead of `1TB/8`? Did I misunderstand what you mean?

Comment: Sorry for that, it's 1k matrices you're right. It doesn't matter if you store 1TB/8 on disk, the point is that it is inefficient to process in this format, so when you load this data to be processed, it is better to store it as chars. You can leave the conversion until the last moment if you prefer, but I still think it will be better algorithmically and for clarity and maintenance.

Comment: But how can I load 10 million different files/matrices in a more efficient way. My assumption is if I decrease the size (without compression), my speed will increase accordingly. If there is any better suggestion, I'm willing to listen :)

Comment: Well, first off, how are these files stored currently? I know of no filesystem that supports 10M files in a single directory, so either they are indexed (sorted in a dir-tree), or they are concatenated currently.

Comment: They are in different SANs. I have quite high storage, it is not hard disk.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question; how are they organized?

Comment: Main_dir/db[i]/tree[j]/noise[k], so they are in tree format.

Comment: Good, and what format? Is it delimiter-separated values? (Maybe it would be better either to edit the OP or ask a new question about this).

Comment: I see no point of changing the question, because, I'm asking for what I was asking :)